# Importing SQL Server database from a .sql file

Tags: sql-server, import

I'd like to import a database without knowing its name from a `.sql` file.

In `MySql` server it is easy because there is tools like heidSQL in which I can import easily my database from a sql file but in SQL Server I can't find the method to do it.

I tried to read the file in notepad but the encoding makes the content unreadable.

[image: jj]

When i execute this query `RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = N'C:\Planning\bdd.sql'` i have this
[image: hhh]

1. How can I do it with SQL server?
2. Can SQL Server Management Studio do this task or do I have to install a new tool?

Comment: How did you get this file? `.sql` are script files that should contain readable code which you can open and run from Management Studio. This does not look much usable.

Comment: i can't read it i think its encodage is the reason

Comment: SQL Server backup files are usually named `.bak` and you can restore them with SSMS. However it is possible to name the file otherwise. Perhaps you can try restoring it and see if it's valid backup. Right click on `Databases` node in SSMS and choose `Restore Database...`

Comment: i try it but it didn't work it didn't accept a `.sql` file

Comment: Rename `.sql` file to `.bak` and try it again.

Comment: try running this Query:

RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = N'C:\FileName.sql'

replace correct path.

Comment: Yes, run the query proposed by @VishalGajjar. If it is a valid backup file you will receive info about what it contains. If not you'll get a red message saying it is incorrectly formed.

Comment: see my edit plz

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create an empty database or if you have one already target that one.

Open CMD with elevated privilege and run:

```
sqlcmd -S SERVERNAME -d MYDATABASE -U USERNAME -P PASSWORD -i C:\path\mysqlfile.sql -o C:\path\results.txt
```

basically:

- **-S:** is your servername or localhost
- **-d:** is the database you are targeting
- **-U:** is the username
- **-P:** is the password
- **-i:** is the path to your .sql file
- **-o:** is where the logs file will be saved so if you had problem during the importation you can debug them

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it with SQL Server Management Studio
Here is the instructions how to ! http://technet.microsoft.com/library/Cc966390